# madam:no arrays found in config file or automatically in the customized linux

Tags: linux

I have customized a Linux system with a kernel version of 6.4.0. When starting, the message `madam: no arrays found in config file or automatically` is displayed. What is the reason? I think the way this link (https://askubuntu.com/questions/834903/i-dont-have-a-raid-but-get-the-warning-mdadm-conf-defines-no-arrays) solves this problem is to add the ignore option, but it doesn't really solve the problem, it's just not visible.

[image]

Comment: I guess the reason is that there's no arrays found :) And: is it a problem? Because to me this doesn't look like a problem, just information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that these prints were from `initramfs`, so I blocked this section of code in `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/local` and it disappeared.

```
local_block "${dev_id}"
```

By the way, setting `slumber` to 0 will accelerate the startup speed.

[image]